# How to fix No image file 'imgs/player/Idle/2.png' found in working directory '/Users/admin/python1/Pygame'. in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
class soldier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, char_type, x, y, scale, speed, ):
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
self.alive = True
self.char_type = char_type
self.speed = speed
self.direction = 1
self.vel_y = 0
self.flip = False
self.jump = False
self.animation_list = \[\]
self.frame_index = 0
self.action = 0
self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        animation_types = ["Idle", "run", "jump"]
    
        for animation in animation_types:
    
            temp_list = []
    
            num_of_frames = len(os.listdir(f"imgs/{self.char_type}/{animation}"))
            for i in range(num_of_frames):
                img = pygame.image.load(f"imgs/{self.char_type}/{animation}/{i}" + ".png") 
                img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))
                temp_list.append(img)
            self.animation_list.append(temp_list)
    
        self.image = self.animation_list[self.action][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
```

keeps on giving image file not found error.
I tried changing the name of the file and drag and dropped the image file in the working directory none of them worked.
thank you for your time, I'm waiting for the solution

Comment: Copy and paste the error you're getting. It seems you may need to recompile the code after you dragged and dropped the image into the directory in order for the system to recognize the change, but without the exact error message it impossible to know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!